# Recording Screen with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I recently used the FFmpeg bash commands below to capture a screen recording.

Are there any improvements that I could make to streamline this process?

Or perhaps some settings to reduce the size of the output files?

Ideally, I'd like to capture to mp4 directly. Is this possible?

Any advice generally about FFmpeg screen recording would be most appreciated.

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -y -r 30 -s 1920x1080 -i :0.0 -vcodec huffyuv out.avi
# Then convert it to .mp4
ffmpeg -y -i out.avi -s 1920x1080 -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -b:v 3000k -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 512k -c:a aac -b:a 128k -strict -2 out.mp4
# and remove the .avi
rm out.avi
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, for FFmpeg, input formats and output formats aren't tied to one another, so you can save in any format as long as the codecs are acceptable in the output format.

So, this will do,

`ffmpeg -f x11grab -y -framerate 30 -s 1920x1080 -i :0.0 -c:v libx264 -preset superfast -crf 18 out.mp4`

You may need to add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` after `-i :0.0` for player compatibility.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the last line. What is `-pix_fmt yuv420p` for?

Comment: ffmpeg will try its best to preserve the input pixel format but that format may not be compatible with all players. So, you can then force a specific pixel format for the output.